# dialogflow opening URL google assistant

Tags: android, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have searched a lot i couldn't find answer... so any help is really 
     appreciated, I need to make google assistant responses to my request by 
     opening URL automatically.

Iam not sure if i could do this using custom payload.

all the examples available are displaying cards or clicking on a buttons or 
     about playing media files... anyone have a clue on if I can do that on 
     dialogflow or do I need my own webhook? or any alternative way?

```
 I appreciate your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Dialogflow supports the url redirection, but only when clicking on some button/cards/list selectors. So You may need to handle this in your web-hook.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically open a URL mid-conversation. The user must choose to redirect to a link by clicking a button or some selection as mentioned.

If you wish to forcefully display data from a webpage to the user, you can have your back-end fetch the data, and return it in a response in a conversational manner.